# Can you tell me a quick(ish) way to achieve this photo/illustration effect?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, monochrome

could anyone help me? I need to achieve a similar effect to this illustration for a client and I don't have much time. I want to apply some kind of effect to a photo (probably a black and white photo) to colour in areas of clothing with bold colours --like it was done manually in a magazine print or hand-coloured (it should have an illustration/print feel). How would you do this? Thanks so much, Jon (I have the Adobe suite)[image: photo of man in suit with illustrated effect]

Answer (score 0):

Although very unclear... I assume it's the *suit* in the sample image you are referring to...

---

Create a color layer over the area you want to color...

[image]

Then change the color layer's **Blend Mode**...

[image]

You might want to try a few different blend modes to see which one works best for you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott! Yes my questions was quite unclear, but correct it was the suit I was referring to although I need to learn a lot of the illustration techniques in this picture. Thanks for your reply, I will try it out today. Jon

Answer (score 0):

Extract the figure from its background using a layer mask. You could then use a gradient map adjustment layer for this, perhaps also a curves adjustment layer to darken the image. Clip these adjustment layers to the figure layer. Select the skin areas, and on a new layer above all of these, fill these with a flat colour. Fill the background with a white to blue gradient.

For example

[image]

Comment: .. guess we weren't quick enough `:)`

Comment: Hey this is great thanks. First time using this site and it's brilliant you get such through answers. Really appreciate the help!!!